Is there a way to organize a group of rows by size and then throw a flag if any of them are within a specific threshold of each other?
I have a dataset that looks like this when pivoted long
data<-data.frame(
  ID=c("type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type1","type2","type2","type2","type2","type2","type2"),
  tag=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6),
  value=c(0.2,0.7,0.45,0.4,1,0,0.056,0.12,0.3,0.67,0.09,0.004)
)

Is there a way after grouping by the id to organize the values by size taking the top 3 most and then throw a flag if specific tags are within a threshold of each other and saved.
For instance: if the threshold was set to 0.05 type1 would be [1,0.7,0.45,0.4,0.2,0] and then a flag would be raised that tags 3 and 4 were within the threshold boundary of each other.
The goal is to be able to add a code to each type made up of the top most tags with a note if there are any within the threshold.
So the type one label would be 523 (with a 4 within the threshold) and type2 would be 631 but no flag is thrown as there is not a value within 0.05 of the top 3 values



id
label
flag




type1
523
4 within threshold


type2
631
NA



I am currently able to order it but the internal threshold is what is giving me issues with how to approach the problem.

Welcome to SO! Should Type1-4 value in your example data be 0.4 instead of 0.04? And why would top-3 for type2 be 631 and not 432?

When you say "specific tags" are "within 0.05 of the top 3 values," do you mean there is a value not in the top 3 that is within 0.05 of the #3 value? (Since if it's within 0.05 of #1 or #2 but its not in the top 3, then it is also within 0.05 of #3. And by the same logic #4 would be the only one we'd need to test.)

yes I would like to be able to order the top 3 and then see if the 4th value is within the threshold range

threshold = 0.05
data |>
  arrange(ID, -value) |>
  summarize(label = paste0(tag[row_number() <= 3], collapse = ""),
            within_threshold = paste0(
              tag[row_number() > 3 & 
                    value[row_number() == 3] - value <= threshold], 
              collapse = ""),
            .by = ID)

In type1, the #4 value 0.40 [label 4] is within 0.05 of 0.40, the #3 value.
In type2, the #4 value 0.09 [label 5] is within 0.05 of 0.12, the #3 value.
     ID label within_threshold
1 type1   523                4
2 type2   432                5

Or

thank you this is very helpful. I would still like to retain the ability to see what tags are the ones causing the flag to be thrown if possible.

Updated to reflect this. It should show all labels whose value is within the threshold from the #3 value.

fantastic thank you so much!
